# How to fetch oracle error codes in a query

Tags: oracle

How to fetch error codes of oracle or warning codes?
Like when I create a procedure it shows
Procedure created with compilation errors.

For seeing the errors I need to write
show errors;

Is there any way through which I can get these errors or messages through a sql query?

Comment: `select * from all_errors`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
select * from all_errors
```

In this table have all errors:)

Answer (score 1):

More specific:

```
select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS where NAME = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME' and type = 'PROCEDURE'
```